# How do I get notifications of native screen recorder on android11?

Tags: android, android-11

I don't want users to record video contents of my application. I'm planning to show users an explanation of the error while the screen is recording. So I want to get notifications when device screen is being recorded by native screen recorder.

Is there anybody out there, that has a clue how to do this?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: You can use `FLAG_SECURE` to block most screenshots and screencasts of your app.

Comment: @CommonsWare Thank you for the advice!  But... I'd like to detect the screen record and show users a customized description of error instead of just a black screen while recording

Comment: Sorry, that is not an option.

Comment: @CommonsWare Thank you! I didn't want to give up but I have to :'-(